# How to pass a Set[String] as a query parameter to anorm?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, anorm

I want to form a SQL query that involves a set of strings as a parameter:

```
SQL("SELECT * FROM TABLE somecolumn in {someset}")
.on("someset" -> Set("v1', "v2", "v3"))
```

but the SQL query that the above generates is invalid:

```
play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception [[MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '_binary'??\0sr\0\'scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon?\\c[???m\0L\0+scala' at line 1]]
```

Are Sets/Traversables unsupported as parameter types in anorm or is there a different way to do this?